# Cocoa: natableview resize

Tags: cocoa, resize, nstableview

I hava a simple cocoa app: a 3 columns `NSTableView` in the window.

I set the minimum and maximum size of the window. I'd like to : when I resize the window, the 3 columns are resized, too. It means: in both the minimum and maximum sizes, all the 3 column are shown and each has a width of window.width/3.
I tried the delegate of `NSTableview`:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView sizeToFitWidthOfColumn:(NSInteger)column;
```

But it seemed it was not called because when I resize the window, the parent view of tableview-NSScrollview is resized and the column of the tableview is not effected.
So I wonder how can I reach it out?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I need to support 10.6, I use autoresizing in the nib file.

If there is any better solution, please let me know.